# Best method for retrieving data in XPages and Java

Tags: xpages

I am sorry this isn't a 'coding' question, but after some considerable time on the learning path with XPages and Java I still struggle with finding definitive information on the correct way to carry out the basics.

When developing an XPages application using Java which is the best or most efficient method for accessing data?

1) Setting up and maintaining a View, with a column for every field in the document and retrieving data by ViewEntry.getColumnValues().get(int); i.e. not accessing the document and retrieving the data from the view. Which is what I have been doing but my View Columns are continuing to increase along with the hassle of maintaining column sequences. My understanding is this a faster method.

or

2) Just drop everything into a document using a View only when necessary, but in the main using Database.getDocumentByUNID().getItemValueAsString("field") and not worrying about adding lots of columns, far easier to maintain, but is accessing the document slowing things down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither 1) or 2).

Go this way to manage document's data in a Java class:

- Read document's items all at once in your Java class into class fields
- remember UNID in a class field too
- recycle document after reading items
- get document again with the help of UNID for every read/write and recycle afterwards

Database.getDocumentByUNID() is quite fast but call it only once for a document and not for every item.

*Update*

As you mentioned in a comment, you have a database with 50.000 documents of various types.

I'd try to read only those documents you really need. If you want to read e.g. all support ticket documents of a customer you would use a view containing support tickets sorted by customer (without additional columns). You would get the documents with `getAllDocumentsByKey(customer, true)` and put the Java objects (each based on a document) into a Map.

You can maintain a cache in addition. Create a Map of models (model = Java object for a document type) and use UNID as key. This way you can avoid to read/store documents twice.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your first bullet point Knut.  My question is - is it better to get the data to pass into each class field from view columns or by the individual document items after retrieving the document.

Comment: My suggestion is to read from individual documents but all items at once. Your 2) would read the document for every item again...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I would only get the document once, it was badly written. I will use getDocumentByUNID() in general then rather than waste time with lots of View Columns. Many thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment below David's answer. You might be best with some views in addition to get fast access to certain documents but without the necessity to create a ton of columns in views.

Comment: I guess it looks like there is no definitive best way due to the many variations involved. I like the tip on Map of models. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll often make a custom object to hold a custom objects.  So I can add special methods like getTotalWeight() or something.  This works very well, but I almost never use the "whole database"..  In some instances I've put 20-25,000 objects into my collection object and it works well.  That number isn't too quick to load but my custom objects could use some tweaking which would help that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really great question.  I would first say that I agree 100% with Knut and that's how I code my objects that represent documents.

Below I've pasted a code example of what I typically do.  Note this code is using the OpenNTF Domino API which among other things takes care of recycling for me.  So you won't see any recycle calls.

But as Knut says - grab the document.  Get what you need for it then it can be discarded again.  When you want to save something just get the document again.  At this stage you could even check lastModified or something to see of another save took place since the time you loaded it.

Sometimes for convenience I overload the load() method and add a NotesViewEntry : 
public boolean load(ViewEntry entry) {}

Then in there I could just get the document, in if it's a specific situation use view columns.

Now this works great when dealing with a single document at a time.  It works really well if I want to loop through many documents for a collection. But if you get too many you might see some of the overheard start to slow things down.  One app I have if I "injest" 30,000 docs like this into a collection it can get a little slow.

I don't have a great answer for this yet.  I've tried the big view with many columns thing like it sounds like you did.  I've tried creating a lower level basic version of the object with just needed fields and that was more designed to work on viewEntry and their columns. I don't have a great answer for that yet.  Making sure you lazy load what you can is pretty important I think.

Anyway here's a code example that shows how I build most of my document driven objects.

```
package com.notesIn9.video;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import org.openntf.domino.Database;
import org.openntf.domino.Document;
import org.openntf.domino.Session;
import org.openntf.domino.View;
import org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory;

public class Episode implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String title;
    private Double number;
    private String authorId;
    private String contributorId;
    private String summary;
    private String subTitle;
    private String youTube;
    private String libsyn;
    private Date publishedDate;
    private Double minutes;
    private Double seconds;

    private String blogLink;

    private boolean valid;
    private String unid;
    private String unique;
    private String creator;

    public Episode() {
        this.unid = "";

    }

    public void create() {

        Session session = Factory.getSession(); // this will be slightly
                                                // different if not using the
                                                // OpenNTF Domino API
        this.setUnique(session.getUnique());
        this.setCreator(session.getEffectiveUserName());
        this.valid = true;

    }

    public Episode load(Document doc) {

        this.loadValues(doc);
        return this;

    }

    public boolean load(String key) {

        // this key is the unique key of the document. UNID would be
        // faster/easier.. I just kinda hate using them and seeing them in URLS
        Session session = Factory.getSession();
        Database currentDb = session.getCurrentDatabase();
        Database db = session.getDatabase(currentDb.getServer(), "episodes.nsf");
        View view = db.getView("lkup_episodes");
        Document doc = view.getDocumentByKey(key); // This is deprecated because
                                                    // the API prefers to use
                                                    // getFirstDocumentByKey

        if (null == doc) {
            // document not found. DANGER
            this.valid = false;
        } else {

            this.loadValues(doc);

        }

        return this.valid;

    }

    private void loadValues(Document doc) {

        this.title = doc.getItemValueString("title");
        this.number = doc.getItemValueDouble("number");
        this.authorId = doc.getItemValueString("authorId");
        this.contributorId = doc.getItemValueString("contributorId");
        this.summary = doc.getItemValueString("summary");
        this.subTitle = doc.getItemValueString("subtitle");
        this.youTube = doc.getItemValueString("youTube");
        this.libsyn = doc.getItemValueString("libsyn");
        this.publishedDate = doc.getItemValue("publishedDate", Date.class);
        this.minutes = doc.getItemValueDouble("minutes");
        this.seconds = doc.getItemValueDouble("seconds");
        this.blogLink = doc.getItemValueString("blogLink");

        this.unique = doc.getItemValueString("unique");
        this.creator = doc.getItemValueString("creator");

        this.unid = doc.getUniversalID();
        this.valid = true;

    }

    public boolean save() {

        Session session = Factory.getSession();
        Database currentDb = session.getCurrentDatabase();
        Database db = session.getDatabase(currentDb.getServer(), "episodes.nsf");
        Document doc = null;

        if (this.unid.isEmpty()) {
            doc = db.createDocument();
            doc.replaceItemValue("form", "episode");
            this.unid = doc.getUniversalID();
        } else {
            doc = db.getDocumentByUNID(this.unid);
        }

        this.saveValues(doc);
        return doc.save();

    }

    private void saveValues(Document doc) {

        doc.replaceItemValue("title", this.title);
        doc.replaceItemValue("number", this.number);
        doc.replaceItemValue("authorId", this.authorId);
        doc.replaceItemValue("contributorId", this.contributorId);
        doc.replaceItemValue("summary", this.summary);
        doc.replaceItemValue("subtitle", this.subTitle);
        doc.replaceItemValue("youTube", this.youTube);
        doc.replaceItemValue("libsyn", this.libsyn);
        doc.replaceItemValue("publishedData", this.publishedDate);
        doc.replaceItemValue("minutes", this.minutes);
        doc.replaceItemValue("seconds", this.seconds);
        doc.replaceItemValue("blogLink", this.blogLink);

        doc.replaceItemValue("unique", this.unique);
        doc.replaceItemValue("creator", this.creator);

    }

    // getters and setters removed to condense code.


    public boolean remove() {

        Session session = Factory.getSession();
        Database currentDb = session.getCurrentDatabase();
        Database db = session.getDatabase(currentDb.getServer(), "episodes.nsf");

        if (this.unid.isEmpty()) {
            // this is a new Doc
            return false;

        } else {

            Document doc = db.getDocumentByUNID(this.getUnid());
            return doc.remove(true);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi David, This is exactly the scenario I am trying to get right. A database with many views, the views may only contain a few hundred documents, but the whole application having say 50,000 documents of various types. I am then looping through a view to create an ArrayList or map of objects - e.g objects of all support tickets per customer. So I am trying to understand in general if it is better to hit the 50,000 total documents with a looping getDocumentByUNID() and get the data from the document or to build the map from View Entries and Columns from a specific View. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll need to experiment a bit..  if you really need to have a collection of all 50,000 then I'd try to go for the viewEntry/column Values thing... but you'll have to play with it.. maybe you don't need to preload EVERY field and can lazy load some.  You're on the right track I think... but it does take some time to convert 50,000 documents to objects.  So you also want to be able to do a "please wait" thing...  i did a NotesIn9 on that not too long ago I think

Answer (score 0):

It's all about balance. everything has its price. Big views (case 1) slow down indexing. Opening documents every time (case 2) slows down your code.

Find something in between.